# Conditional joint probability, where does the big O come from

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

So I am looking at conditional joint probabilities and I have stumbled upon this line:

$$P(X\leq x | y< Y< y+h) = \frac{\int_y^{y+h}dy^{'}\int_{-\infty}^x dx^{'}f_{XY}(x^{'},y^{'})}{\int_y^{y+h}dy'f_Y(y')}=\frac{h\int_{-\infty}^x dx^{'}f_{XY}(x^{'},y^{'})+O_1(h)}{hf_Y(y) + O_2(h)}$$

I can see how we get $h$ in the top: $\int_y^{y+h}dy'=h$. I am not quite sure where the $O_1(h)$ comes from, also I have no idea what is going on in the denominator.

Comment: The integrands $\int_{-\infty}^x dx^{'}f_{XY}(x^{'},y^{'})$ and $f_Y(y')$ are presumably not constants as $y^{'}$ varies

Comment: I believe that is the   case

Comment: It should be $y$ instead of $y'$ in the numerator on the right-hand side?

Comment: In the last fraction? It may very well be the case. Thanks